# How can I prevent Table Columns from 'Locking' with kither Table Columns?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am currently creating a Table, in Microsoft 2016.  Whenever I create a new row, there are times where I will 'draw' in a new Column.  The Column is inserted, without a problem.

Where I am experiencing a problem, is when a adjust the Column width.  As soon as the Column 'aligns' with another Column and 'lock' together.  As a result, I can not adjust the Column independently.  Instead, the other 'locked' columns become affected, whenever I try to adjust a particular Column.

Is there a way I can stop columns from 'Locking'?  I have had a look through the Properties but cannot see a suitable option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resize the column width independently, select the specific row, then use the Mouse to drag the particular column line of this row.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is the problem I am having. If I do this, all other Colums, above and below, also move if the Column are aligned.

Comment: @Craig, would you mind you share a screenshot or video about how you resize the column width in your scenario?

Comment: @Craig I am experiencing the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?